# IE - SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee4

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I am using angular and calling http call. In IE getting SCRIPT7002, how to resolve?

Code:

```
        let headersConfig: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        headersConfig = headersConfig.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headersConfig = headersConfig.set('Authorization', '<auth-token>');

        httpClient.post(URL, JSON.stringify(request),
        { headers: headersConfig }).map(data => {
            //Success
        }
```